# how to implement postprocess filtering of response as middleware in node?

Tags: node.js, middleware

As part of authorization-rules I'd like to centralize logic as to what fields of a json-response are returned to the user.

To me, it makes sense to somehow implement this as some sort of postprocess-filter implemented in node-middleware.

Apart from the question whether it's considered good practice to change the output of a REST-endpoint based on some authorization-rules (I'm not sure, please share if you've got a strong opinion), I'm uncertain how to implement such a post-process filter.

I tried to implement it by listening to `response.finish` and have the filter kick in, but that's too late. i.e.: the response was already send.

Instead, what would be considered best practice for post-processing responses in Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can perform your data operations at any part of communication chain, so if require to do some post data filter you can do your CRUD operations in a middle ware and then filter it in other step something like

```
AUTHENTICATION-(next)->AUTHORIZATION-(next)->OPERATIONS-(next)->LIMITS-(next)->RESPONSE
```

where each step except RESPONSE reffers to a middleware that will alter the request object with the pertinent information to pass to the next middleware